# How can an Azure CosmosDB provisioned with Autopilot be created programatically using Azure Az CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cli

How can a CosmosDB collection with Autopilot be created via the Azure Az CLI?

I cannot see any mention of autopilot on the Az CLI cosmosdb collection document page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cosmosdb/collection?view=azure-cli-latest), nor the release page announcing the availability of autopilot (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/whats-new-in-azure-cosmos-db-nov-2019/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's NOT AVAILABLE yet as per the [Cosmosdb team.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/11137)

> thank you for opening this issue. As this feature is still in preview,
>   we are going to wait to add support via the CLI for now. We do not yet
>   have a timeline for adding this feature, but we plan on adding it once
>   we have more feedback. We are tracking this internally as work item
>   541736. I will update once we get closer to adding support.

Soon it will be [generally available](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/39148330-allow-the-configuration-of-cosmos-autopilot-throug).